# i got error message while retrieve nodes

Tags: php, xml

While using this code I got this type of error message.

> The XML page cannot be displayed
>   Cannot view XML input using  style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the >Refresh button, or try again later.
>   Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document. Error processing resource `<c>text</c><c>stuff</c>`

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
  <b>
    <c>text</c>
    <c>stuff</c>
  </b>
  <d>
    <c>code</c>
  </d>
</a>
XML;    
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
echo $xml->asXML();
$result = $xml->xpath('/a/b/c');
foreach ($result as $id => $child) {
    echo "<c>".(string)$child."</c>";
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: yes. i need to retrieve childnodes like <c>text</c><c>stuff</c>.. what i wanna do for that

Comment: do you want to echo the values/contents of `<c>` tags or return this page as xml

Comment: i don't want to return this page as full xml.. i just need <c>text</c><c>stuff</c> this xml node..

Comment: sorry..i am new to php.. i need <c> values also.. that is <c>text</c>. and why we need to create newelement, we can't display <c>text</c> this alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below this code.. i need to retrieve particular node that is code means what i want to do.

```
<?php
    $string = <<<XML
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>text</c>
    <c>stuff</c>
    </b>
    <b>
    <c>code</c>
    </b>
    <d>
    <c>item</c>
    </d>
    </a>
    XML;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
     $xml->asXML()."<br>";
       // echo "<c>".(string)$child."</c>";
        foreach( $xml->children() AS $child )
    {
        //run any query you want on the children.. they are also nodes.
       $name1 = $child;
        //echo "<pre><c></pre>".$name1."<pre><c></pre><br>";

        foreach( $name1->children() AS $child1 )
        {
            $name2 = $child1->getName();
            $child2=$child1;
            // echo $name2."--".$child2;
            echo "&lt;".$name2."&gt;".$child2."&lt;&frasl;".$name2."&gt;"."<br>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: In that above example.. how to retrieve particular node.. i.e., if b node had value like <b id="1"> means it will return b's child nodes..

Answer (score 1):

Check the XML source you do output, your XML is missing a document element and escaping.

A better approach is to copy the nodes using DOM:

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
<a><b><c>text</c><c>stuff</c></b><d><c>code</c></d></a>
XML;

// load source XML and create Xpath instance
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadxml($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);

// create target document with document element
$target = new DOMDocument();
$root = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('e'));

// copy nodes from source to target
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/a/b/c') as $child) {
  $root->appendChild($target->importNode($child));
}

// output target
echo $target->saveXml();
```

Demo: https://eval.in/161474

Comment: sorry..i am new to php.. i need <c> values also.. that is <c>text</c>. and why we need to create newelement, we can't we display <c>text</c> this alone.

Comment: XML always needs a single document element, a single `<c>...</c>` ist possible but not `<c>...</c><c>...</c>`. This has nothing to do with PHP, but all with XML. The message in your question is from the browser, not PHP.